# Custom error messages in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following validation. I am using the new sintaxis of Ruby on Rails, where can be declared many validations to a same attribute, but I need a custom error message for each validation

```
validates :user_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true


  for example  validates_presence_of :user_name, message: "Can not be empty"
               validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, message: "Must to be unique"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) for examples:

`validates :user_name, uniqueness: { message: "Must to be unique" }`